# how can I do reverse sort in python language?

Tags: python

I have write python code,get the key from the log,and do descent sort by advert_sum,when i call sorted function,

```
sorted(dict, cmp=lambda x,y: cmp(adver_num), reverse=False)
```

it reports `not adver_num`. How can i fix it? `dict[].adver_num`? I try some ways,and it still failed.

```
import re
dict={}
class log:
    def __init__(self,query_num, adver_num):
        self.query_num = query_num
        self.adver_num = adver_num
f = open('result.txt','w')

for line in open("test.log"):
   count_result = 0
   query_num = 0
   match=re.search('.*qry=(.*?)qi.*rc=(.*?)dis',line).groups()
   counts=match[1].split('|')
   for count in counts:
      count_result += int(count)
   if match[0].strip():
     if not dict.has_key(match[0]):
        dict[match[0]] = log(1,count_result)
     else:
        query_num = dict[match[0]].query_num+1;
        count_result = dict[match[0]].adver_num+count_result;
        dict[match[0]] = log(query_num,count_result)
     #f.write("%s\t%s\n"%(match[0],count_result))

sorted(dict,cmp=lambda x,y:cmp(adver_num),reverse=False)
for i in dict.keys():
    f.write("%s\t%s\t%s\n"%(i,dict[i].query_num,dict[i].adver_num)
```

Comment: Is it `advert_sum` or `advert_num`?  Both are mentioned up at the top.

Comment: Don't use cmp=, it's slow, use key= instead, it's both faster and easier.

Comment: Calling your variable `dict` is probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, `dict` can't be sorted, you need to use a `list`. Second, `sorted` function does not modify its argument, but returns a new list. Try calling `sorted` on any dictionary, you'll get a sorted list of keys as a return value.

Comment: @liumilan: You can sort the contents of a `dict`, but the result is a `list`, not a `dict`. Dictionaries have no concept of ordering.

Comment: @MarceloCantos  after run sorted(dict.iteritems(),key=lambda x:x[1].adver_num,reverse=True) .It can't work.The output is still disorder.How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to capture the result of `sorted` and use it to access the dictionary.  This is what @MarceloCantos attempts in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

`sorted` returns a sorted copy of whatever you give it, which in this case is a list of the keys in `dict`. I think what you want is this:

```
s = sorted(dict.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1].adver_num, reverse=True)
for (i, _) in s:
    …
```

I'm not sure why you passed `reverse=False`. That's the default (which means it's redundant, at the very least), and means that you *don't* want it sorted in reverse order.

Comment: yes,it should be reverse=True.But it can't work.From the result,it still can't be sorted.What x[1] means?

Comment: `lambda x: whatever(x)` creates an anonymous function which receives a single parameter named `x` and returns `whatever(x)`.  So in this case the sort receives an item from the dictionary and calls that `x`, and sorts on the value of `x[1].adver_num`.

Comment: @liumilan: Did you use `for (i, _) in s:` or are you still trying to iterate over the original `dict` (which won't work)?